# Remove recent clock entry if it is less than X minutes

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I'd like to keep the clock entries simple and clean. I am thinking of defining an function to remove the most recent entry if it is less then 3 minutes when I clock out.

There's an similar function called `org-remove-empty-drawer-at` in the org library but it's looks rather complex to me. So I wonder if any one had wrote one before?

Thanks,